# Correct form for dateFormatter

Tags: iphone, events, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm pulling dates from an xml feed that has this form

12/10/2010 19:30:00

and I'm using this form of the setDateFormat method to recognize the date

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss"];
```

but it's constantly throwing an exception saying the date that results is nil, leading me to suspect I don't have the right form to recognize the date.

Do I have the correct form, or am I missing something?

Thanks for any insight you can provide on this.

Here is more information about the function in which this error is thrown - and the error occurs on the first date that it finds - which is this date 12/10/2010 19:30:00:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:self.currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:self.currentType forKey:@"type"];
        [item setObject:self.currentSummary forKey:@"description"];
    [item setObject:self.currentTeacher forKey:@"teacher"];
    [item setObject:self.currentDate forKey:@"pubdate"];
    [item setObject:self.currentLink forKey:@"link"];               

    // Parse date here
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];


    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];


    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.currentDate];


        [item setObject:date forKey:@"date"];

        [items addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}
```

Comment: The format looks ok.  Show more of the surrounding code including the actual line giving the exception.  Does it return nil only for this specific date+time or all?

Comment: Before the dateFromString line, NSLog the value of self.currentDate.  What does it show in the debugger console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format looks good to me.
Check the date return from XML before formatting.
if you are having any other tags/characters than date dateFormatter gives error.

Comment: Thanks..could you tell me how to check the date return here?

Comment: ok...this looks like it's a problem with the original date feed...thanks..I'm going to need to figure out how to correct it with code